# OpenCV in python on mac installation with homebrew

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to get opencv for python on my mac running mavericks.  After googling/stack overflow seraching I tried:

```
brew install homebrew/science/opencv
```

Based on the terminal output it looks like that worked.

To verify I wrote a python script that simply contains:

```
import cv2

print("Hello")
```

I get `no module named cv2`.  When I try looking at the installed modules by typing `help('modules')` I don't see cv or cv2.  This leaves me with two conclusions: either I didn't properly install opencv or `import cv2` isn't actually importing cv2 and python is looking in the wrong location for cv2.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [guide](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2013/08/22/update-installing-opencv-on-mac-mountain-lion/), if you add the following to your `.bash_profile` it should fix your issue:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: That does work -- thank you.  Only problem is that I also use python3 for some other stuff (and will hopefully transition 100% as soon as opencv 3.0 comes out).  That solution seems to kill python3.x (it wants me to unset pythonpath before I use python3).

Comment: What you should do is create a VirtualEnv then install the specific python version you want to work with along with opencv.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your pythonpath,
but you would probably be better served running 'brew install python' so that you are not using system python.  System python and brewed python look for modules in different locations.

EDIT:
Asked questions, updated the above.

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: Crap.  This should have been a comment shouldn't it have?

Comment: When I echo path I get /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
I'm using system python

Comment: Yes, if you have questions, it is better to ask using comments and then post an answer once you get the info you need.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't have done it that way, since I can't comment, but probably could have let someone else take it.

Comment: Try putting usr/local/bin at the front of your path.  Also, did you do 'brew install python' or are you using native mac python?

Comment: I'll try that.  Using system python.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Changing the order of the paths didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: It would only have done anything if you were using brewed python.  Try using brewed python (safer and better anyway).  brew install python.

Comment: I can't comment on the above, since I just joined, but you can avoid the whole virtualenv mess by using homebrew.  brew install python, brew install python3.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Install X code from App Store.

1. Uninstall Homebrew
2. Uninstall and clean Anaconda
3. Reinstall Anaconda and Homebrew
4. Install OpenCV using `conda install -c menpo opencv3`

It should be good to go. Remember import it as `import cv2`
In case of any library errors try this `conda install -c conda-forge basemap fiona`

Hope it helped